# Should I select : This is a full trust application

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, security

I am developing app in Visual studio 2010, my app is constantly connected to the internet. Should I activate `This is a full trust application` in Security tab?

If yes what does it exactly means? I was reading msdn docs but I can't understand it. I need something in short lines of when to use this feature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't worry, it doesn't influence the security of your internet connection, but it influences how the .NET framework treats your application. So - yes you can activate it without danger, but if possible you should declare in your code which level of access your application needs to refine security. To explain the details:

**Full trust** means that your application needs all rights that the .NET framework provides. As a developer, you declare which trust level your application needs in order to be able to run, this is known as **"code access security".**
Code access security means that you're telling the compiler via attributes which kind of operation your code needs in order to succeed.

The **.NET framework** in turn estimates how much trust the application should be granted:
For example, if you deploy your application to a remote computer, which is accessible via a network share outside of your intranet*), then the .NET Framework gives it less than "Full trust". This is known as an **"evidence based" security model,** which is implemented through so-called **managed code**.

**Managed code** means that your .NET application is compiled into **MSIL** (**M**icro**s**oft's **I**ntermediate **L**anguage) by the **["Roslyn"-Compiler](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview)** and then "just in time" (i.e. just when you execute it, unless you choose to [create native code explicitly via NGEN **before** execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.100).aspx)) into CPU-specific machine language by the **["RyuJIT"-Compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/06/19/the-ryujit-transition-is-complete/?utm_source=vs_developer_news&utm_medium=referral)**. This allows to establish an additional abstraction layer, which in turn enables the .NET Framework to control what your code does and to allow it or - if not - to throw an security exception.

All the code you write for the .NET framework in one of the languages C# or VB.NET is per default managed code. However, there are (very rare) situations where you want to embed **unmanaged code** - also known as "unsafe code" (in .NET terminology) as well. One way is to create an "unsafe" section in your code (which I only mention here for completeness - i.e. in case you might have come accross with it in source code).

As I mentioned before, you specify what the code does via attributes, but you can also change the rules that apply on your local computer to change this behaviour through the **.NET security settings.**
Usually it is a good idea to specify as precisely as possible which rights your application needs, and to be as restrictive as possible.

If you're interested, you can find more here:
[Exploring the .NET Framework Security Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee677170.aspx)

*) Thank you for your hint, Damien! Indeed, earlier versions of the framework gave resources on the network (network shares) less trust, with .NET 4 desktop and local intranet connections have full trust.

Comment: Re: network share - that changed in [.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff527276.aspx): "Desktop and local intranet applications are granted full trust."

Comment: Thank you on this detailed answer